# Visited links in a single-page application do not change color when clicking on them

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, user-agent

I tried googling the information about it but did not find anything suitable.

I create SPA with react and react-router-dom. When I click on link of my default page I go to the page without rebooting, but color of my visited link don't change. Сan dear experts say something about this? Probably there is the place in w3c standard (I didn't find it), that say something about it.

Comment: Could you provide us with some of the code? or a demo?

Answer (score 0):

Use NavLink and set attribute activeClassName="your classname"

**UPD.** Firstly, you need to set className to NavLink and assign :visited style for your class. But in SPA your link wont be defined as visited, so you need some logic for checking history of links. You can try to use localstorage for it or anything else

Comment: Active and visited are two different things.

Comment: Firstly, you need to set className to NavLink and set :visited style for your class. But in SPA your link wont be assigned as visited, so you need some logic for checking history of links. You can try to use localstorage for it or anything else

Comment: Sorry, but activeClassName is used for current (active) page. But I need to indicate user that he used this link and return back to previous page